# Mostrar imagenes GIF de una carpeta

Tags: php, html, web, xampp

Tengo en local una carpeta llamada 2D donde hay imagenes .GIF, y estoy intentando de crear un php para que me mustre por el navegador estas imagenes, pero no consigo. Eso es lo que he hecho:

```
// Ruta de la carpeta
$carpeta = "C:/xampp/htdocs/web/2D/";

// Obtener la lista de nombres de archivos
$archivos = scandir($carpeta);

// Filtrar los nombres de archivo para eliminar los directorios "." y ".."
$archivos = array_diff($archivos, array('.', '..'));

// Mostrar la lista de nombres de archivo
foreach ($archivos as $archivo) {
    echo $archivo . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Y me muestra la lista de los gifs pero sin imagen:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El planteamiento está mal. Para mostrar imagenes, necesitas un elemento HTML para mostrarlos, `echo` no funcionará acá. Lo que estás haciendo al momento de hacer un `echo $archivo`, es simplemente mostrar la cadena del nombre del archivo. Prueba a realizar un `echo` de algún componente `img` o similar de html.

Answer (score 1):

como te habian dicho el planteamiento esta incorrecto.

Cuando queremos mostrar las imágenes en tu navegador usando PHP, necesitas generar las etiquetas HTML (`<img>`) correspondientes en tu script PHP. Ejemplo:

```php
<?php
$carpeta = "C:/xampp/htdocs/web/2D/";

$archivos = scandir($carpeta);

$archivos = array_diff($archivos, array('.', '..'));

foreach ($archivos as $archivo) {
    /* Verificar si el archivo es un GIF */
    if (pathinfo($archivo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) === 'gif') {
        /* Generar la etiqueta <img> con la ruta del archivo */
        echo '<img src="' . $carpeta . $archivo . '" alt="' . $archivo . '">' . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Si implementas la etiqueta entonces si el navegador debe reconocer que es un recurso e interpretarlo como tal.

Esto funciona para cualquier imagen, otros tipo de recursos requieren otras etiquetas especificas como [`object`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp) o [`source`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_source.asp)

incluso dependiendo de lo que pretendas hacer tambien puedes implementar esas otras etiquetas.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que la extension es .GIF en mayusculas no .gif en minusculas y sigue mostrando lo mismo que antes.

Comment: entonces debes asegurarte que la url y el archivo es accesible ... si tomas lo que esta dentro de `src=""` y lo pones en el navegador debe cargar la imagen o error 40X ... nos dices para ver ...

Comment: a y las extensiones deberian ser en minusculas todas XD